# How to remain in the 3.2.4 release of R

Tags: r, ubuntu, cran

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and work with 3.2.4 Revised. I would like to remain with this version when 3.3.0 gets released. However if I block the CRAN repository in /etc/apt/sources.list I will not receive updates to the 3.2.4 (even the distribution specific updates).

Is there another way to stay in the 3.2.4 release?

Comment: you can have multiple installations in your user directory. A lot of people use this when they need access to multiple versions.

Comment: @JeremyS What you say is certainly true for Windows systems, but much less obvious in the case of Linux distributions. The default behavior on Linux is to erase the previous R version with every upgrade.

Comment: This is really a Linux question, not a programming one. Consider moving it to "ask ubuntu" maybe?

Comment: You can always build any packages you need updated from source using `install.packages()`.

Comment: @RHertel Not if you designate where it installs to. That is why I specifically said to install it into the user directory (i.e. /home).

Comment: @JeremyS Agreed. I never had any doubt that this can be done. What I meant is that it requires some tweaking. While in Windows older versions of R are automatically kept, the *default* behavior in Linux is to keep only the latest installation.

Comment: @Thomas If I remember correctly, there are sometimes also updates of the current R version. I believe that the OP is concerned that such updates may not be available if the entry in /etc/apt/sources.list is removed.

Comment: @RHertel you seem to only be thinking about root installs. I am talking about a user install into a home directory

Comment: @JeremyS I understood what you mean and I agree. I was just trying to explain why sometimes it can be difficult. The [installation guide at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) suggests sudo / root installations.